# Charts looking the same

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

The following are the charts of DJIA, NASDAQ and S&P 500 for June 13, 2020. The charts look very similar with the same ups and downs. In the morning, DJIA was 700 points high, then went down, up, down and then up again.

My questions is:

1. The companies in these indexes are different. For example, there is more technologies in NASDAQ. If that is correct, the trades are different for these indexes, so these three charts should look different. What is making these indexes look the same?

[image]

Comment: They are not all the same, their % increases are all different. The DJIA is made up of only a few very big companies, so if they are moving and nothing else is, they will also cause the other indexes to move in the same direction but to a different %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old stock market cliche' is that "A rising tide lifts all boats." Major market indexes capture the mood of the market and therefore   historically, over long periods of time, they are highly correlated and  generally have a similar return.  During shorter time periods (day, week, month), the return may vary a bit.

The NASDAQ and the S&P 500 contain far more companies than the DJIA.  Because of their size, the NASDAQ and the S&P 500 are very highly correlated and will move in the same direction on virtually every trading day, assuming that it's not a flat day.

Over short periods of time, the DJIA may or may not correlate as closely because it only has 30 constituents.  A large price move in  one stock exerts an undue influence on the average (as compared to the other larger indexes).  While a $1 change in the price of one stock has the same effect on the index's value as a $1 change in the price of another DJIA stock,  the method of calculation (see the Dow Divisor), large moves in the more expensive components will affect the value of the DJIA more than they would on the SPX.  A recent example of this is that when the market collapsed in late February, the DJIA led the way down, losing more each day and each week than the SPX.  And the reverse happened during the recovery.

If you look at a short term rolling period correlation between any two of these indexes, you'll see that they correlate highly, with as much as a 10  basis points correlation variation.  But on some days, there's no variance at all.  You happened to select a day when there was no variance, hence the very similar graphs.

An easy way to visually see the correlation between two securities over time is  to use an indicator that's called the Comparative Relative Strength. Divide the daily price of index A by that of index B.  When the numerator  (index A) is stronger, the graph will rise. When the denominator  (index B) is stronger, the graph will decline.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows only one day. If you look over a period of several years, you should see bigger difference.

There are certain periods of time where the correlation between individual stocks is high, which is why they move in lockstep.

Also, if you look at the composition of the three indexes, you'll see that all of them include the tech stocks that have driven the recent performance, e.g. Facebook, Amazon, Apple, Netflix, Alphabet (Google), Microsoft, etc.